# Is there a NuGet library which implements a log4net appender for .Net Core SignalR (not ASP.Next SignalR)?

Tags: .net-core, signalr, log4net

I need to send log4net output to a SignalR server.

The SignalR server uses .Net Core SignalR, not ASP.Net SignalR.

Is there a NuGet library which implements this functionality?

If so, please provide the name of the library.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I'm aware of this rule, but this is a yes/no question.  I searched NuGet and was not able to find one.  I'd like to communicate with someone in a position to create this library.  It's not a "which one is best for this purpose" question.  I posted on Twitter, but tweets are much more difficult to find.

Comment: Lets say the answer is "yes" then. Does that help?

Comment: Not interested in a comment fight. :) If you knew the answer and posted it, yes it would be helpful.  In the old days, my grandfather would answer "Do you know what time it is?" with "Yes".  I will edit the question so it asks for the name of the library.

Comment: That's my point though. Apologies for the terrible dad joke, but it did serve the purpose of saying that this is a request for a software library :)